# How can I format a character given date and time as date and time in 24h format?

Tags: r

I'd like to thank you beforehand for the help!

I'm working with some data in R studio, and I have a csv with chr formatted dates that are given like this:

4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM

Reproducible input:

```
library(tidyverse)

h_Calories <- tibble(
    ActivityHour = c("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", "5/12/2016 1:00:00 AM", "6/12/2016 1:00:00 PM"))
```

What I want is:

- Format this string as date and time in 24h format
- Divide it into multiple columns to perform further analysis.

The dates are stored in a dataset called 'h_Calories', under a column called 'ActivityHour'

What I did was this:

```
h_Calories <- h_Calories %>%
  mutate(ActivityHour = as.POSIXct(ActivityHour, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

Thing is, this code strips away the AM/PM bits so it ends up with an ambiguous result.

Once again, thank you for the assistance! I'm still new to R!

Comment: Welcome - I'd have a read of the `?strptime` help file, particularly the 'Details' section which lists all the `%` codes for formatting of dates/times, which will point you to the `%I` and `%p` hours and AM/PM indicator options.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  There are _numerous_ identical questions here so you could try the (pretty excellent) search. I.e. [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+parse+am+pm+time) finds R questions for to 'parse AM PM time'.   Once you have it parse, the formatting is by default sane (i.e. ISO 8601 in 24h format) rather than idiosyncratically insane as done around here. Happt 4th!

Comment: Hi Martin! Welcome to StackOverflow. I added a reproducible input for your question. Feel free to change it if it doesn't fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `lubridate` and `hms`, or base R:

```
library(hms)

# using base R
h_Calories %>%
    mutate(ActivityHour = as.POSIXct(ActivityHour, format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), 
            time = format(ActivityHour, "%H:%M:%S"),
            date = as.Date(format(ActivityHour, "%d/%m/%Y")))

# using lubridate and hms (preferred)
h_Calories %>%
    mutate(ActivityHour = dmy_hms(ActivityHour), 
            time = as_hms(ActivityHour), 
            date = as_date(ActivityHour))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  ActivityHour        time   date      
  <dttm>              <time> <date>    
1 2016-12-04 00:00:00 00:00  2016-12-04
2 2016-12-05 01:00:00 01:00  2016-12-05
3 2016-12-06 13:00:00 13:00  2016-12-06
```